# CSV value passed into SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is my stored procedure input parameter, I want split the column name and column value to insert the temp table, and next to move the main table production table.

Temp table like columnname and value

Example

```
Create Proc sample (@name VARCHAR(MAX))

@NAME='column1=value1,column2=value2,column3=value3'

Create Table #temp(columnname varchar(max),value varchar(max))
```

My Question :

1. How can I split the input parameter in desired format
2. How to find the column Value

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: which database server are you using?

Comment: It would be a lot easier, if You had XML.

Comment: Don't make all your columns type `VARCHAR(MAX)` - that's a **REALLY BAD** idea!

Comment: Try to refactor your logic. DB is for **storing** data not for **processing** it. I'd suggest you to use table valued parameters.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to direct you to this detailed article written by Erland Sommarskog a while ago, http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html.

Resources for split functions can be found here, http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=50648.

Here's my favorite split function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split (@sep char(1), @s varchar(512))
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
    WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
        SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + 1)
        FROM Pieces
        WHERE stop > 0
    )
    SELECT 
        pn,
        SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END) AS s
    FROM Pieces
)
```

I believe there are several topics already on StackOverflow with other examples.